# How can I display additional information from my dataframe in an hPlot (rcharts)

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

```
head(table)

                      RM_NAME MATURITY         SD        MEAN     YIELD   YIELD.1        DELTA       RETURN   NORMALIZE N
1 AED FX Implied Money Market       1M 0.12146003 0.013998847 0.1687345 0.1730082 -0.004273678 -0.024702169 -0.31863170 1
2 AED FX Implied Money Market       1Y 0.02959845 0.003497085 0.5810012 0.5594854  0.021515795  0.038456401  1.18111994 2
3 AED FX Implied Money Market       2M 0.04773910 0.003427750 0.2112821 0.2139478 -0.002665666 -0.012459421 -0.33279159 3
4 AED FX Implied Money Market       3M 0.03411471 0.002880936 0.2751758 0.2736954  0.001480400  0.005408931  0.07410275 4
5 AED FX Implied Money Market       6M 0.02096178 0.002728893 0.3998672 0.3932815  0.006585714  0.016745548  0.66867668 5
6 AED FX Implied Money Market       9M 0.02680865 0.003392600 0.4879713 0.4723653  0.015606000  0.033037992  1.10581435 6

n1<-hPlot(N ~ NORMALIZE,  data=table, type="scatter", group="RM_NAME")

n1$show('inline', include_assets = TRUE, cdn = TRUE)

n1$show('server')
```

I would like to know how to add additional information from my data.frame to the tag that appear above any data point inside the graph?
[image]

In order to be able to see the "rm_name" I need to group by rm_name, but as you can see in the graph it is not the best thing to do. So I would like to group by other column but still be able to see which rm_name I am pointing out.

Additionally If someone would have some insight on how can we do [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction-advanced.html) with `rCharts`, I would really appreciate some help in how to interactively select a point inside an `rCharts` graph and display it somewhere else to create a report.